# Overlay image to make tutorial in Android app

Tags: android, overlay, showcaseview

In many applications, I have seen that there is a welcome screen or tutorial that explains how the application works by overlaying explanations on top of the activity. For instance, in Android itself, the welcome screen with "Make yourself home".

I would like to know what techniques can be used for that.

*Edit*: screenshot of "make yourself home
[image]
[image]

Comment: In suppose this was already asked but searching "overlay image tutorial" leads to tons of irrelevant results.

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of an example?

Comment: @Squonk A picture is worth a thousand words

Comment: That'll be an `Activity` using `@android:style/Theme.Translucent`

Comment: @Squonk I think you can write answer instead of that comment. Also, I am a little worried about handling screen size for view that are not on the edges of the screen or that depend on API level (like menu vs action bar)

Comment: Posted as an answer. Sorry, I'm not sure I can help with your screen size problem. Give the 'translucent' theme a try and then post a new question if you have any problems.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Is it this one? https://github.com/Espiandev/ShowcaseView

> The ShowcaseView (SCV) library is designed to highlight and showcase specific parts of apps to the user with a distinctive and attractive overlay. This library is great for pointing out points of interest for users, gestures, or obscure but useful items...
>
> The library is based on the "Cling" view found in the Launcher on Ice-Cream Sandwich and Jelly Bean...
>
> To use ShowcaseView, use the Builder pattern.
>
> As an example:
>
> ```
> new ShowcaseView.Builder(this)
>     .setTarget(new ActionViewTarget(this, ActionViewTarget.Type.HOME))
>     .setContentTitle("ShowcaseView")
>     .setContentText("This is highlighting the Home button")
>     .hideOnTouchOutside()
>     .build();
> ```
>
> You can use styles to customise how a ShowcaseView looks.

Comment: As the project says, it is called "Cling" in the Android launcher2 project

Comment: This library does not currently support the new `Toolbar` implementation in `appcompat-v7`.  It will crash if you attempt to utilize a `Target` on any item or view located inside the `Toolbar` (ActionBar)

Answer (score 28):

There are now 3 alternatives for displaying some tutorial of an activity :

- [amlcurran / ShowcaseView](https://github.com/amlcurran/ShowcaseView)
- [EspianDev / ShowcaseView](https://github.com/Espiandev/ShowcaseView)
- [stephanenicolas / RoboDemo](https://github.com/stephanenicolas/RoboDemo)

The first one being the best of the 3.

Comment: All three of these seem to be deprecated. :(

Answer (score 1):

From your screen shots that looks like an `Activity` set to use...

```
@android:style/Theme.Translucent
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a popup window or a dialog. Both should have a similar effect.

Comment: Or possibly an `Activity` using a dialog theme.