# How to Overlay Image

Tags: android, overlay

I followed this tutorial [here](http://www.jdepths.com/2013/01/how-to-overlay-view-over-everything-on.html) and got a question: how to overlay an image instead of a color? Can anyone answer please?

Comment: if your Overlay is a View, you can simply override onDraw() and draw bitmaps.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12548585/1168654