# Show the function of Android using an activity

Tags: android

I just want to know how to make something like when I install an Android application. The function of the activity is shown for example what particular button does..just to let the user know what this particular activity/or a button in an activity do.or the over all function of my product you must have seen this, I'm just curious about that and want to implement. Only when you run the application for the first time after installation.

Comment: Looking for this?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12148381/overlay-image-to-make-tutorial-in-android-app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this Third Party Library

https://github.com/amlcurran/ShowcaseView

or

You can do it on your Own with an Layout above Top of you Activity with alpha and some text describing Actions which when clicked ok will be gone